# eww: How to tell the page is loaded

Tags: elisp, emacs24, eww

In my elisp code, I am trying to use `(eww url)` to open a page. How can I know that the page loaded? I need to process the *eww* buffer.

Emacs 24.4

Comment: I'd suggest `M-x report-emacs-bug` to request a new eww hook for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `eww` doesn't appear to call a hook after it finishes rendering a page, so you'll need to hook into `eww` at a lower level:

```
(defun eww-render-and-do-stuff (status url &optional point)
  (eww-render status url point)
  (do-stuff))

(let ((url "http://emacs.stackexchange.com"))
  (url-retrieve url 'eww-render-and-do-stuff (list url)))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. It works for me. But I have some questions about your answer. I tried to replace "eww-render-and-do-stuff" with "eww-render" and put the real do stuff code after "url-retrieve", it doesn't work as expected. So my question is what's different between use eww-render-and-do-stuff function and inline code directly?

Comment: See `C-h f url-retrieve` and the `CALLBACK` argument.

Comment: @EnzoChi, `url-retrieve` runs asynchronously — it may return before the page has finished downloading, and let the download continue in the background.  If you put `do-stuff` after `url-retrieve`, it will probably run before the download is finished, and, due to limitations in the Emacs Lisp engine, probably prevent the download from completing.